# MS Excel- Populate cell with a percentage based on number of cells coloured?

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I'm looking to populate a cell value with a number based on how many cells have the colour green.

example 1:

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 (E1- Answer '15%' will appear here)
G  NG NG NG (G= Green, NG= Not Green)
```

Another example:

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 (E1- Answer '30%' will appear here)
G  G  NG NG (G= Green, NG= Not Green)
```

`=IF(GetFillColor(A1)=4,"1",AND IF(GetFillColor(A1:B1)=4,"2"), AND  IF(GetFillColor(A1:C1)=4,"3"), AND IF(GetFillColor(A1:C1)=4,"4", "0"))`

GetFillColour:

```
 Function GetFillColor(Rng As Range) As Long
    GetFillColor = Rng.Interior.ColorIndex
 End Function
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: What is `GetFillColor`?  Is this a UDF you wrote?  Please include the code?

Comment: If it's a UDF, you can probably just write another UDF to do this. I did something similar a few years back.

Comment: GetFillColour is a function I have to retrieve the cells color. So if it equals 4 then the colour is green.

Comment: I want `GetFillColor`, how come I'm missing out‽

Comment: Try this `=SUMPRODUCT((GetFillColor(A1:D1) = 4)*1)/4`

Comment: You say GetFillColor is a function.  There is no built in function that will directly count and average the color.  So if `GetFillColor` is available to you as a function then it is coded in vba.  If it is coded, please provide the code in your original post.

Comment: I was hardcoding the percentage in myself, I don't need to calculate the average. I'm using the cells to calculate when a task is complete. So for example 1, E1 could be A, and then for example 2 E1 could be B. I just want to be able to tell the difference when 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 of the cells are green.

Comment: You have two good answers, Like I said there is no built function that will do this.  You will need to do some work arounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your getfillcolor function with:

```
Public Function getfillcolor(rng As Range, color As Long) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Interior.color = color Then
    i = i + 1
    Else
    End If
Next cell
getfillcolor = i
End Function
```

Now you have your sum directly in the specified cell.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without a function in Microsoft visual basic? So just as an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using *helper* cells (and no VBA):

- Create a named formula:  `=GET.CELL(38,OFFSET(INDIRECT("RC",FALSE),-1,0))`
  I've called mine **CellColour**.
- Place the formula `=CellColour` 1 cell below your coloured cells.
  The Offset in the formula tells it to look at the row above.
- The formula will display the number 10 for cells coloured green (RGB = 0,255,0).
- Now use a simple formula to calculate the percentage: `=COUNTIF(A2:D2,10)/COUNTA(A2:D2)`

You'll need to press F9 to update the formula result.

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/20611-info-only-get-cell-arguments.html

Comment: Good point - I wouldn't use that approach myself.  I'd use a method that wouldn't involve counting colours - such as entering 10 in the cell (or more likely TRUE/FALSE) and conditional formatting if I really needed the colours.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Still don't have what I wanted to do but still its a big help! I'll have another mess around with it...